# Path Integral Problem

Tags: integration

Could anyone help understand why my answer disagrees with the given answer?

let the exact differential $dz = 3x^2(x^2+y^2)dx + 2y(x^3+y^4)dy$

Find $\int\limits_c dz$ from (1,2) to (2,1).

Here's my answer:

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=3x^2(x^2+y^2)$

$\therefore$

$z = \int(3x^4+3y^2x^2) dx$

$\therefore$

$z = \frac{3}{5}x^5+y^2x^3+f(y)$

and

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 2y(x^3+y^4)$

$\therefore$

$z=\int(2x^3y+2y^5)dy$

$\therefore$

$z = x^3y^2+\frac{1}{3}y^6+g(x)$

so, in order to have $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ we need

$f(y)=\frac{1}{3}y^6$ and $g(x)=\frac{3}{5}x^5$

$\therefore$

$z = \frac{3}{5}x^5+y^2x^3+\frac{1}{3}y^6$

$\therefore$

$\int\limits_c dz$ from (1,2) to (2,1) =

$\left[\frac{3}{5}x^5+y^2x^3+\frac{1}{3}y^6\right]_{(1,2)}^{(2,1)}$

= $(\frac{96}{5}+8+\frac{1}{3})-(\frac{3}{5}+4+\frac{64}{3})$

= $\frac{8}{5}$

But the answer given in the book I'm using is $\frac{9}{2}$

Thanks,
Mitch.

Answer (score 1):

I write this only to confirm that I get the same $z$ as you (one could add an arbitrary constant, but that does not really change anything), and the same final answer. It looks like the book has a misprint.

Comment: Thank you very much. After much checking and rechecking I had come to the same conclusion but one always doubts. An independent verification closes the issue. Thanks again.